# AngularJS Validation on <select> with a prompt option

Tags: validation, angularjs, select

I have the following code for a select drop down input that is styled in Bootstrap.

```
<select class="form-control" name="businessprocess" ng-model="businessprocess" required>
    <option value="">-- Select Business Process --</option>
    <option value="C">Process C</option>
    <option value="Q">Process Q</option>
</select>
```

Before the user is able to submit this form, he or she must select a business process.

So I have put the `required` directive on the select statement, however because the first option tag has `-- Select Business Process --` that still counts as a selected option, and thus the required flag is met, and therefore the form validates even though no actual Business Process is selected.

How can I overcome this issue?

Thank You.

Comment: Can you create an attribute directive with link property that will setup a listener for onchange event ant and validate things there?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This approach could/should solve your issue:

1) declare the options inside of your scope:

```
$scope.processes = [
    { code: "C", name: "Process C" },
    { code: "Q", name: "Process Q" }
];
```

And 2) use this declaration:

```
<select class="form-control" name="businessprocess" ng-model="businessprocess" required
    ng-options="c.code as c.name for c in processes" >
    <option value="">-- Select Business Process --</option>
</select>
```

The trick here is in fact, that during the angular cycles, will firstly fix the issue that the the current value is not among the `processes` options. So, the default would be set to:

`<option value="">-- Select Business Process --</option>`

and `required` will be working as expected *([more details](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select))*

Comment: It's all about having that empty <option> tag in your HTML, not as an option in 'processes' :) Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 4):

you can initial the value of selector in controller:

```
<select class="form-control" name="businessprocess" ng-model="businessprocess">
    <option value="A">-- Select Business Process --</option>
    <option value="C">Process C</option>
    <option value="Q">Process Q</option>
</select>
```

in Controller:

```
$scope.businessprocess = "A" ;
```

or "C","Q",whatever you want, so the select will always have value. i think you don't need "required" here in select.

If you don't want an init a value. also do some extra effect when user don't select it.

```
<select class="form-control" name="businessprocess" ng-model="businessprocess" myRequired>
    <option value="">-- Select Business Process --</option>
    <option value="C">Process C</option>
    <option value="Q">Process Q</option>
</select>
```

then write the directive:

```
model.directive("myRequired", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {},
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                if(iElement.val() == ""){
                    //do something
                    return;
                } else {
                    //do other things
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: I get that, but I purposefully want the user to select something. I don't want a default there.

Comment: i have reedited my answer, hope it is useful for you.

Answer (score 2):

**JS**

```
    angular.module('interfaceApp')
  .directive('requiredSelect', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elm, attr, ctrl) {

        if (!ctrl) return;
          attr.requiredSelect = true; // force truthy in case we are on non input element

          var validator = function(value) {
            if (attr.requiredSelect && ctrl.$isEmpty(value)) {
              ctrl.$setValidity('requiredSelect', false);
              return;
            } else {
              ctrl.$setValidity('requiredSelect', true);
              return value;
            }
          };

          ctrl.$formatters.push(validator);
          ctrl.$parsers.unshift(validator);

          attr.$observe('requiredSelect', function() {
            validator(ctrl.$viewValue);
          });
      }
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

a best way and straight one is to use:

**HTML**

```
<select name="businessprocess" ng-model="businessprocess"  required>
        <option selected disabled value="">-- Select Business Process --</option>
        <option ng-repeat="v in processes" value="{{v.id}}">{{v.value}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add form, like:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
     <form name="mainForm">
    <select name="businessprocess" ng-model="businessprocess"  required>    
        <option value="">-- Select Business Process --</option>
        <option ng-repeat="v in processes" value="{{v.id}}">{{v.value}}</option>
    </select>
    <span class="error" ng-show="mainForm.businessprocess.$error.required">required</span>
</form>
</div>
```

**js**

```
angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
   $scope.processes = [{
        id: "C",
        value: "Process C"
    }, {
        id: "Q",
        value: "Process Q"
    }];
}
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nF7eJ/57/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code snippet

```
<select class="form-control" name="businessprocess" ng-model="businessprocess">
    <option value="A" disabled selected hidden>-- Select Business Process --</option>
    <option value="C">Process C</option>
    <option value="Q">Process Q</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "disabled" to the first option:

```
<select class="form-control" name="businessprocess" ng-model="businessprocess" required>
<option value="" disabled>-- Select Business Process --</option>
<option value="C">Process C</option>
<option value="Q">Process Q</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Form is invalid until user selects any other value than "Choose..."

```
<select name="country" id="country" class="form-control" formControlName="country" required>
    <option selected value="">Choose...</option>
    <option *ngFor="let country of countries">{{country.country}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this code, can be usefull for this... in this case the form is called myform

```
<select ng-model="selectX" id="selectX" name="selectX"  required>
                                            <option  value="" ></option>
                                            <option  value="0" >0</option>
                                            <option value="1">1</option>
                                          </select>

    <span style="color:red" ng-show="myform.selectX.$dirty && myform.selectX.$invalid">
    <span ng-show="myform.selectX.$error.required">Is required.</span>
    </span>
```