# Why Angular Drop down always Valid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dropdown

Can you tell me why below drop down always says valid ? In other words without selecting anything it says valid.`required` attribute is not working.

**JS**

```
 vm.foreclosureActionHeader = {};
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="foreclosureActionsForm" role="form" novalidate class="form-validation left-aligned">
     <select id="refereeNameDropDown" name="refereeNameDropDown" required
        ng-options="a.id as a.firstName + ' ' + a.lastName for a in vm.referees"
        ng-model="vm.foreclosureActionHeader.refereeId"
        ui-jq="selectpicker"
        ui-options='{ iconBase: "famfamfam-flag", tickIcon: "fa fa-check" }'
        data-live-search="true" title="@L("SelectRefereeName")">
        <option value=""></option>
     </select>
</form>
```

I have used same way as mentioned on the above answer.But still it's not working. Can you tell me why ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS Validation on <select> with a prompt option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858918/angularjs-validation-on-select-with-a-prompt-option)

Comment: Could you try to remove other directives and see once whether it is working or not also check browser compatiblity http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp, a simple jsfiddle here which works https://jsfiddle.net/pr9yxtnd/, could you try creating a jsfiddle/plnkr e.g. to show the problem

Comment: @TomShen I have used same way as that solution.But still it's not working.Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the solution.Cheers :D

**JS**

```
vm.init = function () {
if (vm.foreclosureActionHeader.refereeId == 0) vm.foreclosureActionHeader.refereeId = null;
}

vm.init();
```